# How to get the Coordinates of a cropped image with respect to the original image?

Tags: python, image-processing, crop

I had to crop an image 50X50 which i did through using this code:

```
def crop_center(img,cropx,cropy):

x=img.shape[0]

y=img.shape[1]

startx = x//2-(cropx//2)
starty = y//2-(cropy//2)
return img[starty:starty+cropy,startx:startx+cropx]
```

Now i need to get the coordinates of this cropped pic with respect to the original image. How to do so ?

Comment: have you even understood the code you already have? I don't think so, otherwise you wouldn't ask this. Don't just copy and paste, think!

Answer (score 0):

You alread used those coordinates to crop the image.

[starty:starty+cropy,startx:startx+cropx]

Comment: I need to plot a box on an image file of 1024X724 . I first needed to create patches of 200X200 and if it ran on a test , then crop 50X50 from that particular patch . Now how do I get to plot the box on the original image(1024X724) using the coordinates of the 50x50 cropped file

Comment: @HergeBristol that is not what you have asked in your question, update your question and provide more details. which library and what it is you actually want to know!
This kind of operations are usually done applying ROIs, not by cropping.

Comment: I had an image of the dimension 1024x724 . I created ovelapping patches for this image using a function I created . Now i ran each of these patches through a function and if it yields a desirable result then I had to plot a box on the original image of the dimension of 50x50 on the original image by checking on the coordinates of the patch which yielded the positive result . I now understand that this can't be done with cropping.

Comment: @HergeBristol it can be done by cropping, although it is not very common as cropping takes additional computation whereas ROIs only restrict your algorithms to a range of pixels. If you want to stick to cropping you simply have to store the source coordinates of that crop. its all just a matter of adding a few coordinate offsets. simple maths...